# Android parse push notification with message count like whatsapp

Tags: android, web

Sending push notification .. correct but notification from same parse  User it shows repeated messages .I want message count like whatsapp.....pls help me

Comment: you have to append all string with "\n" and set string in setContentText(message)

Answer (score 1):

That is called **InboxStyle Notification**, here is sample code to implement that.

```
Notification notification = new Notification.InboxStyle(new Notification.Builder(context)
.setTicker(message)
.setSmallIcon(icon)
.setContentTitle(title)
.setContentText(subTitle)
.setNumber(3)
.setContentIntent(intent))
.addLine("Hi")
.addLine("Hello")
.addLine("How are you?")
.setBigContentTitle("Custom message")
.setSummaryText("+8 more")
.build();
```